# Windows Phone 7 - tracking user location in background?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I am working on WP7 application to track user location. I need to track location with GeoCordinateWatcher (using  StatusChanged / PositionChanged events) even when device screen is being locked.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is already well-documented in this [MSDN doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681691%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) (there is even a [sample available](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj662935%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)). In Windows Phone 7, this is **not possible** - there are a lot of API implications that target only Windows Phone 8.